# Proving the Deduction Theorem

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

In propositional logic, how do we prove metalogical concepts like the Deduction Theorem, which says

$$\Delta, A \vdash B \implies \Delta \vdash A \to B$$

Hopefully I am using the symbols correctly. I'm not sure if these have more formal representations (I am uncomfortable using $\implies$ since its meaning isn't standardized).

Anyhow since we are operating outside of logic does this mean our proof of this theorem must resort to informal reasoning in some regard? How do we proof this result when $\to$ is just an arbitrary connective? Are we introducing an interpretation first?

Comment: In which formal system you want to prove the deduction theorem? [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system)?

Comment: Propositional logic

Comment: Does it depend on the specific system in terms of axioms and inferences? I guess I'd like to understand Hilbert system and Natural Deduction first? Is this theorem proved informally?

Comment: The notation is fine. $\Longrightarrow$ is commonly used for metalanguage implications like this.

Comment: Meta-logical doesn't mean informal. It just means the logical framework in which you are studying some other logical framework. It can be formal or informal. Usually it's informal because most of math is done informally, but I referenced [a mechanized proof of soundness, completeness, and indirectly the deduction theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08744) in a previous question.

Comment: As for whether it depends on the specific system, it absolutely does. For example, the deduction theorem is basically true by definition for typical natural deduction systems or sequent calculus systems. Namely, the deduction theorem is the implication introduction rule of natural deduction or the right implication rule for the sequent calculus. Usually when one talks of the deduction theorem they mean in the context of a Hilbert-style system where it is not at all a trivial result.

Comment: The Deduction Theorem is a result specif for a calculus (or proof system). For propositional logic (with axioms and modus ponens), see [here](https://dspace.lu.lv/dspace/bitstream/handle/7/1308/Detlovs_Podnieks_Math_Logic.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) page 41.

Comment: "I am uncomfortable using $\implies$ since its meaning isn't standardized": Then don't write $\implies$! State the theorem in English: If $\Delta, A\vdash B$ then $\Delta\vdash A\to  B$.

Comment: I suggest not thinking of it as "How do I prove $(X \vdash Y) \to (\vdash X \to Y)$" but rather "How do I convert a proof of the form $X \vdash Y$ into a proof of the form $\vdash X \to Y$".  Like if you were trying to write a program to make the conversion autonomously.

Comment: There is no proof for 'propositional logic', which usually refers to a semantic system, but only a proof for a propositional calculus which has a collection of axioms and rules of inference. Even ignoring natural deduction systems, the axiom system matters.  A proof is for the system with axiom set {CCpqCCqrCCpr, CCNppp, CpCNpq} under uniform substitution and detachment is *much* more complicated than a usual proof for a system with the same rules of inference, but having {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCNpNqCqp} as the axiom set instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the last paragraph first, there is no presumption of an interpretation here. To say whether or not $\to$ could be any arbitrary connective in this case, it depends on what you mean. If the question is whether, from the same axioms and rules of inference, you could derive the same thing for $\vee$ or $\wedge$, the answer is no; the proof rules treat the connectives differently. If the question is whether you can derive it regardless of what kind of changes you made to the semantics, the answer is yes; changing the semantics may break things like soundness or completeness, but it won't change the notion of proof.

And since this theorem is stated outside of the logic in question, it means the proof lives in some kind of metalanguage, but the metalanguage may be another formal language (like ZFC or something). In practice, the proofs you read will usually be presented informally, as a sketch of how you *could* potentially implement it in some more formal language, but lots of these theorems have been proved in a completely formal way with software like Coq.

As for how to prove it, I steal this approach for a Hilbert system from Bell & Machover's *A Course in Mathematical Logic*. First, we need to understand what a deduction is for a Hilbert-style proof system. Given a set of formulas $\Phi$, a deduction of $\alpha$ from $\Phi$ is a sequence of formulas $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ such that (A) $\varphi_n=\alpha$, and (B) for each $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$, $\varphi_k$ is either an axiom, a member of $\Phi$, or there are $i,j\lt k$ with $\varphi_j=\varphi_i\to\varphi_k$ (i.e. $\varphi_k$ can be obtained by modus ponens from previous formulas in the proof). If there exists a sequence like this, we say $\Phi\vdash \alpha$.

So let's single out a particular member of $\Phi$ and call it $\beta$, and assume we have any particular deduction $D=[\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n=\alpha]$.  There are basically two cases.

**Case 1:** $\varphi_k$ is an axiom, or in $\Phi$, we have already that $\varphi_k\to (\beta\to\varphi_k)$ is an axiom, then we can add to our deduction $D$ the three additional steps

- $\varphi_k$
- $\varphi_k\to(\beta\to\varphi_k)$
- $\beta\to\varphi_k$

The new deduction is now a deduction $\Phi\vdash\beta\to\alpha$.

**Case 2:** If there are $i,j\lt k$ with $\varphi_j=\varphi_i\to\varphi_k$, then we can add to $D$ the new lines $$[\varphi_i\to(\beta\to\varphi_i),\:\beta\to\varphi_i,\:(\varphi_i\to\varphi_k)\to(\beta\to(\varphi_i\to\varphi_k),\:\beta\to(\varphi_i\to\varphi_k)].$$ Another axiom of most Hilbert systems is $$(\beta\to(\varphi_i\to\varphi_k))\to((\beta\to\varphi_i)\to(\beta\to\varphi_k)).$$ If in addition to the four steps we just added we also add this axiom and the obvious ones that follow from applying modus ponens, then the new deduction is again one that $\Phi\vdash\beta\to\varphi_k$. In particular, we obtain $\beta\to\alpha$ since $\alpha=\varphi_n$.

Comment: Commenting as I read but how can we be proving things in e.g. ZFC etc when these things often rely on the very logical systems we're defining? Isn't there an air of circularity to that?

Comment: Also I can't quite tell what your start and end result is given all these relabelings

Comment: That's an issue that's been addressed in other questions, and can't really be addressed briefly. But no, the circularity is only apparent.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your second comment, since I'm not relabelling anything... The proof proper begins at "So let's single out". Let me see if I can make the structure a little clearer.

Comment: Also what's contained in $\Phi$ exactly / where do we presume these formulas come from? Won't they inevitably come from axioms or modus ponens themselves?

Comment: @user525966 I can write an interpreter for a programming language in that very same programming language. There's no circularity here because I can use a *different* interpreter to interpret the interpreter I defined. To return to logic, just because I'm formalizing first-order logic, say, in a first-order theory doesn't mean I'm using my formalization of first-order logic as the definition of the meta-first-order logic. It could be formulated in some other logical framework such as type theory, or it could be left unformalized.

Comment: What I mean is I can't tell the full result you are proving (like the one liner in my post, what's the equivalent you're proving?)

Comment: $\Phi$ is a set of formulas. And no, they don't just need to be axioms or come from modus ponens. Part of the purpose of logic is that we often have a theory we want to study that is phrased in the language of logic, and then we want to deduce its consequences. $\Phi$ is the collection of extra formulas that we "assume" *in addition* to those of pure logic.

Comment: And the full result I'm proving is just the deduction theorem as you posted it, using a slightly different notation (which notation I explain).

Comment: What lets us take b->a from a->(b->a)?

Comment: The fact that we have already assumed $\alpha$ appears in the deduction or is one of our assumptions; it's an application of modus ponens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard proof of the deduction theorem that I know. For each statement $C$ that occurs in the proof $P_1$ of $B$ from $\Delta\cup\{A\}$, the statement $A\to C$ is proved in the proof $P_2$ of $A\to B$ from $\Delta$.

For example, in the Hilbert system, if $C$ is a statement that occurs in $P_1$ then $C$ is an axiom or $C\in\Delta$ or $C=A$ or $C$ follows from modus ponens. If $C$ is an axiom or if $C\in\Delta$ then we may derive $A\to C$ in $P_2$ from the axiom $C\to(A\to C)$ and modus ponens. If $C=A$ then we prove $A\to A$ in $P_2$ (which is either an axiom or an easy consequence of the axioms). If $C$ follows from modus ponens then $C=Y$ where both $X$ and $X\to Y$ have been proven in $P_1$. Inductively, we have that $A\to X$ and $A\to(X\to Y)$ have been proven in $P_2$. Then we may derive $A\to C$ in $P_2$ from the axiom $(A\to(X\to Y))\to((A\to X)\to(A\to Y))$ and two applications of modus ponens.